# Python - Slicing reverse string not working

Tags: python-2.7

I am a new to python, trying to reverse a string but not working why ?

```
name='Sam Floyd'
reverse = name[8:-1:-1]
```

Comment: Your start index is `8` which is correct because the string ends at index 8 but your stop index is index `-1` which is the last index in the string(same as index 8). If you change the stop index to `0`, the slicing terminates at index 1. You need to remove the stop index so that  the slicing terminates at the begining of the string.
Then you have: 
`reverse = name[8::-1]`
or in short
`reverse = name[::-1]`
 Please refer to this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to use that one :)

```
name='Sam Floyd'
reverse = name[::-1]
```